# combined client 3.6.0 jar file missing

Tags: selenium

[image]

please anyone help on this. The jar file missing and cannot invoke webdriver related classes in the eclipse.

Comment: remove that jar frome there and refer this link https://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: Try to dump all the required jars in a single place preferably in a directory within the drive partition where _Eclipse_ is installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can [download](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.6/) the jar file again and upload it again and it will work fine.
You just need to use selenium 3.6.0.jar file nothing else.